# -webkit media query HTML5 Validation

Tags: html, media-queries, w3c, w3c-validation

The following code will not validate with W3C HTML5 checker because the media query -webkit.... begins with a symbol and not a letter what is an alternative solution so that my code will validate although this is valid HTML media queries I believe.

`media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is valid HTML media queries

It isn't. You are using the `-webkit` prefix (indicating an experimental vendor implementation and not a standard).

You can either use it, or you can be valid.

(There may also be a way to hide it from a validator by injecting it with JavaScript, but that adds complexity and more likelyhood of things breaking. Validation is a tool, not a competition).

Comment: so in your preference you would just leave it ? or remove it or 'inject' it ?

Comment: Injecting it with JS is complexity that you don't need. Complexity breaks things. You don't need it, don't do it. Just don't worry about the validation errors.